# rails: text_area size

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sign in:
http://glowing-fire-495.heroku.com/newpost

email: admin@admin.com
pw: password

or you can create your own account.

I am using wmd for the rich text editor for the Content.

However, I am not sure how to control the size of the text area box.

The code for it right now is:

```
  <div class = "field">
     <%= f.label :content%><br/>
     <%= f.text_area :content, :cols =>30, :rows => 100%>   </div>
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery and do it like SO: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set in `custom.css` on line 365 the `height` of the textarea to 4ems. Try adding a different value to resize it.

Comment: If you are using css to style the form field you might need to use min-height so that the input conforms to the text that is input.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the text area size in a Rails app like this:

```
<%= f.text_area :content, :size => "30x10">
```

Change value inside the size param according to your need. Hope this helps.